# How to change the size the multiples textures in a plane in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like know how to change a size image in a geometry.faces. In my example I have four static images of Google Maps. But my imagens would have 640x640 pixel, but all images have 1280x1280. I would know how to change the size texture to put only inside de geometry.faces.  My code is below.
[image]

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1280, 1280, 2, 2 );
var texturaPlano0 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-16.679361,-49.252408&zoom=14&size=600x600&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE');
var texturaPlano1 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-16.679361,-49.20100802620749&zoom=14&size=600x600&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE');
var texturaPlano2 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-16.727278, -49.222213&zoom=14&size=600x600&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE');
var texturaPlano3 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-16.736064, -49.252853&zoom=14&size=600x600&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE');
// materials
var materials = []; 
materials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {  map: texturaPlano0 }) );
materials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texturaPlano1 }) );
materials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texturaPlano2 }) );
materials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texturaPlano3 }) );
// Set images 
geometry.faces[ 0 ].materialIndex = 0 ;
geometry.faces[ 1 ].materialIndex = 0 ;
geometry.faces[ 2 ].materialIndex = 2 ;
geometry.faces[ 3 ].materialIndex = 2 ;
geometry.faces[ 4 ].materialIndex = 1 ;
geometry.faces[ 5 ].materialIndex = 1 ;
geometry.faces[ 6 ].materialIndex = 3 ;
geometry.faces[ 7 ].materialIndex = 3 ;

// mesh
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
scene.add( mesh );
```

Comment: I would avoid `MeshFaceMaterial` and simply create a `THREE.Group` with four child plane meshes -- each with a single texture.

Comment: Hi! I used THREE.Group. It's working. Thank you.